# Nuxt Axios Dynamic url

Tags: proxy, axios, nuxt.js

I manage to learn nuxt by using following tutorial

https://scotch.io/tutorials/implementing-authentication-in-nuxtjs-app

In the tutorial, it show that

```
axios: {
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api'
},
```

it is point to localhost, it is not a problem for my development,

but when come to deployment, how do I change the URL based on the browser URL,

if the system use in LAN, it will be `192.168.8.1:3000/api`

if the system use at outside, it will be `example.com:3000/api`

On the other hand, Currently i using adonuxt (adonis + nuxt), both listen on same port (3000).

In future, I might separate it to server(3333) and client(3000)

Therefore the api links will be

```
localhost:3333/api

192.168.8.1:3333/api

example.com:3333/api
```

How do I achieve dynamic api url based on browser and switch port?

Comment: You can access it with the localhost address because you are running it on the localhost. When you access it from an external machine, you can use your IP. Please clarify what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @DezsoGabos I want change the axios api url based on the browser url (with different port maybe)

Comment: Dynamic api url is not about changing the base URL. You need a basic understanding of what a hostname is, and how the IP address is mapped to a certain hostname, and how the DNS server resolves these. If you would like to reach a certain hostname from the outside, you can add the IP and hostname pair to that machines hosts config.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need baseURL in nuxt.config.js.

Create a plugins/axios.js file first (Look [here](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend)) and write like this.

```
export default function({ $axios }) {
  if (process.client) {
    const protocol = window.location.protocol
    const hostname = window.location.hostname
    const port = 8000
    const url = `${protocol}//${hostname}:${port}`
    $axios.defaults.baseURL = url
  }
```

Comment: How can we do this on Server side?

Answer (score 2):

A late contribution, but this question and answers were helpful for getting to this more concise approach. I've tested it for localhost and deploying to a branch url at Netlify. Tested only with Windows Chrome.

In client mode, windows.location.origin contains what we need for the baseURL.

```
# /plugins/axios-host.js
export default function ({$axios}) {
  if (process.client) {
    $axios.defaults.baseURL = window.location.origin
  }
}
```

Add the plugin to nuxt.config.js.

```
# /nuxt.config.js
...
  plugins: [
     ...,
    "~/plugins/axios-host.js",
  ],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a year and a half old now, but I wanted to answer the second part for anyone that would find it helpful, which is doing it on the server-side.

I stored a reference to the server URL that I wanted to call as a Cookie so that the server can determine which URL to use as well. I use `cookie-universal-nuxt` and just do something simple like `$cookies.set('api-server', 'some-server')` and then pull the cookie value with `$cookies.get('api-server')` .. map that cookie value to a URL then you can do something like this using an Axios interceptor:

```js
// plguins/axios.js
const axiosPlugin = ({ store, app: { $axios, $cookies } }) => {
  $axios.onRequest ((config) => {
    const server = $cookies.get('api-server')

    if (server && server === 'some-server') {
      config.baseURL = 'https://some-server.com'
    }

    return config
  })
}
```

Of course you could also store the URL in the cookie itself, but it's probably best to have a whitelist of allowed URLs.

Don't forget to enable the plugin as well.

```js
// nuxt.config.js
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/axios',
```

This covers both the client-side and server-side since the cookie is "universal"